# Django views best practice : explicit or implicit context?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm wondering if there is a 'best' solution between explicit context definition and implicit use of `locals()` parameter in view rendering.

The original way of doing is to 'declare' each variable to be used in the context of a view, thanks to a dictionary, but Django proposes some shortcuts and also offers the ability to take into account all variables defined in a view to be part of the context.

Are there any differences between both options (context variable defined in a dict vs 'locals()'), and is one of them 'better' (and why?)?

Btw (subsidiary question): I'm quite new to Django and I never used `return HttpResponse(...)` but always `return render(...)`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `locals()` is antipattern. IMO you should always define what you wanna pass to template. If you pass `locals()` you can also overwrite `context_variable`

Take a look into zen of python: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

`Explicit is better than implicit.`

Render function is kind of "shortcut" to `HttpResponse`, `render_to_string`, (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) so it's god idea to use it :)

Comment: Thanks @Sharpek for your answer! But, in terms of shortcut, what's the difference between using `locals()` instead of `context_variable`, and using `render` instead of `HttpResponse` ?